# Custome Size 2D Array with Fitting For Loops

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am creating a 2D array that can have any custom size `1x1, 2x2, 3x3 .... nxn` and depending on what the size of the array is, it gets filled with `0` to `(n^2)-1`, so if it is `2x2` it outputs:

```
3 2 
1 0
```

It should be something like this `int[,] arr = new int [n, n];`, to create the 2d array, but how would the for loops be constructed?

what I have tried

```
using System;

namespace moveElement {
  public class move {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      int n = 3;
      int[, ] arr = new int[n, n];

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
          Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
      }
    }

  }
}
```

The result of the code:

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Comment: Here is a full documentation for that : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int k  = 0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
   {
      arr[i,j] = k++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Or maybe `int k = n * n - 1` and `k--`.

Comment: @zellez you get exactly what you want - the array is filled with numbers (altho reversed). Displaying the array, however, is a thing, as I and Ivan can see, that you can already do yourself.

Answer (score 1):

full code to the question:

```
using System;

namespace moveElement
{
    public class move
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 3;
            int[,] arr = new int [n, n];

//Ivan Smyrnov solution


            int k = (n * n) - 1;
                    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                        {
                        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                            {
                                 arr[i,j] = k--;
                                                    }
                                                        }
//Ivan Smyrnov solution 


                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
            }

        }
    }
```

Output when `n` is `3`:

```
8 7 6 
5 4 3 
2 1 0
```